# Dijkstra algorithm React Native

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, matrix, dijkstra

I developed a react native application that implements dijkstra algorithm using Graphs, i want to now if is possible build dijkstra algorithm using matrix in React Native.

Thank you guys.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be?

Comment: I cant find any example in react native , thats why i asked. Thank you :)